# Datatable Compute string from the Database

Tags: c#, datatable

What I am trying to achieve is to get formula expressions from the database and execute it on runtime. After reading what I found is the following;

```
    // Consider these values are coming from the DB
        int voltageln1 = 220;
        int voltageln2 = 220;
        int voltageln3 = 220;
        int currentln1 = 10;
        int currentln2 = 10;
        int currentln3 = 10;


        string formula = $"(({voltageln1}*{currentln1}*{0.85})+({voltageln2}*{currentln2}*{0.85})+({voltageln3}*{currentln3}*{0.85}))";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        double result = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Compute(formula, ""));
        MessageBox.Show("Result:" + result);
```

Above code works fine when string formula has the $ sign beforehand.

But what I receive from the database as follows where there is no $ sign in front.

```
string thatcamefromtheDB = "(({voltageln1}*{currentln1}*{0.85})+({voltageln2}*{currentln2}*{0.85})+({voltageln3}*{currentln3}*{0.85}))";
```

Is there any way to add that $ sign or format that text somehow?

Comment: Be warning: your code will break on a culture where a non-dot decimal separator is used. For example, ru-RU.

Comment: That's not the case at the moment but thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try Double.Parse:

```
  double data= ((Double.Parse(voltageln1)*Double.Parse(currentln1)*0.85)+(Double.Parse(voltageln2)*Double.Parse(currentln2)*0.85)+(Double.Parse(voltageln3)*Double.Parse(currentln3)*0.85))";
```